# how to setup authentication flow for react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to add an authentication flow to my react native application using the react-navigation module.
I want the url to change based on the visited page therefore i've added linking.

Right now i'm testing on the web. When i run the code it works fine and fx. if a user is not loggedin it goes to the authentication page and if you type in some gibberish file path it returns to the authentication path. But if you type in one of the other screen names fx. onboarding and that statement can't execute it returns the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Is there a way to avoid this error? I've also tried with multiple navigationcontainers where each container had only the screens within that particular area fx. if the user wasn't autherized it only showed the authentication page. This worked fine but then the redirect to the onboarding page didnt work.

Here is my routes. The idea is if token is empty show authentication page, else: if user profile is not complete: show  onboarding, else: show  the users settings:

```
...
    
const app = expo.name;
const titleExtension =  "some app";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
const linking = {
  prefixes: ["https://localhost:19006","app://"],
  config: {
    screens:{

      authenticate: "",
      onboarding: "/onboarding",
    
      profile: "profile/:userId",
      settings: "/settings"
     }
  }
}

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking} 
      fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>

      <Stack.Navigator 
        headerMode="none" 
        initialRouteName="/"  
        screenOptions={{
              cardStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#fff'
              }
        }}>
  
          {!localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
            <>
    
              <Stack.Screen name="authenticate" component={Authenticate} options={{title: app + " | " + "Lad os starte"}}/>  

            </>
          ) : (
            <>
                
              {!localStorage.getItem("login") ? (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="onboarding" component={OnboardingView} options={{title: app + " | " + "Vi er der næsten"}}/>          
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  
                  <Stack.Screen name="settings" component={ProfileSettingsView} options={{title: app + titleExtension}}/>  
                  <Stack.Screen name="profile" component={ProfileView} options={{title: app + titleExtension}}/>
                               
                </>
              )}

            </>
          )}

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this error? Based on other stackoverflow questions i think it's setup the right way except that a lot of the other posts didn't have the linking property.

Comment: Did you tried to setup the not found path in linking? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#handling-unmatched-routes-or-404

Comment: how have you solved this issue?